# how to wait for response of multiple request for xml parsing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I have 5 html request to get data from web service. I am requesting in for loop.

```
-(void)loadPreviewsData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) 
    {
        if(i==1)
        {
            //request 1

        }
        if(i==2)
        {
           //request 2
        }
        //3 to 5 

       request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

   NSURLConnection *myConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(myConnection)
    {
         HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
         HUD.labelText=@"Please wait.";
         myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView  *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Connection could not be established!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}// end for loop
}//end loadPreview
```

> all response has a lot of data and i am saving response data into array, but it is not waiting for first response and making another request.
>   finally for loop will finish and next view will load but array is not filled because parsing is not done yet because copy of data into array is not completed so there is an error.
>
> i tried to `sleep(5);` in `-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser` method, but it is not valid, because response time is depends on network traffic. i can't understand what to do please help.
>
> I tried Following answer also but can't understand [Wait for code to finish execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615939/wait-for-code-to-finish-execution)

Comment: have u tried adding the wait view before starting the for loop, and removing after the end of for loop..?

Comment: i have no idea how to wait for finish Parsing only tried sleep(3); but   it will wait for specific time and no idea about wait view. how to implement it?

Comment: The main question is why you are using the callback where the data is not ready as the callback where the data is ready. Are trying to display the view when the last called request is finished (but there's no guarantee it is fetched and parsed as the last) instead of checking whether all the requests are finished ? Please note, the solution you linked is designed for the background thread as it blocks the thread, it also not of a good performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using asynchronous methods with same delegate. 
This means you make the 5 requests at the same time.

You could make a queue in Grand Central Dispatch: 
http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/

Answer (score 1):

I think u want to do synchronous http request. You should read about this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371638/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-vs-threading-in-an-iphone-app).
And I found this open source library will help u [ASIHTTPRequest](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-asihttprequest.html)

**Note:** ASIHTTPRequest Project owner is no longer support for that project.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the HTTP requests.

then you can have a separate class which does the XML parsing.

this will allow you to easily receive the response and pass it to the XML class ( you will have to create a new object of the XML parser class to handle requests separately ) and the XML will parse it.

sometimes when you have different responses of different structure you will have to inform the XML class of the current parsing. for example

```
MyXMLParserClass *pars = [[MyXMLParserClass alloc] init];
pars.ParsingOperation=1;
```

**or**

```
pars.ParsingOperation=2;
```

then in the XML parser class you can check the operation.

```
if(self.operationType==1)
{
   // Your code
}
else if(self.operationType==2)
{
  // your code
}
```

hope this helps.